# Multi page Report via JasperServer

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working on report that contains multi page report. Every page having same column name and Logo, only data is different.

Let me try to give one example.

Report: Want to generate all Student's Mark for last 10 year. We thought there were 60 students. We only want Top 10 ranker marks.

Page 1:

Student Name: XYZ
 Year       | Subject1 | Subject2 | Subject3 |
Sem-1 2016  |   99     |    98    |    99    |
Sem-2 2016  |   98     |    99    |    98    |
TOTAL 2016  |  197     |   197    |   197    |

Page 2:

Student Name: PQR
 Year       | Subject1 | Subject2 | Subject3 |
Sem-1 2016  |   97     |    98    |    97    |
Sem-2 2016  |   98     |    97    |    98    |
TOTAL 2016  |  195     |   195    |   195    |

Same as for up to Top X Student for per page report.

Is it possible to create such type of report without merging separate report?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you already considered using groups? it sounds to me that this could be a very suitable scenario... by the way, what are your main concerns?

Comment: Try to post some jrxml of what you tired creating a [mcve]

Comment: @FabioFantoni: Thanks for your answer: I understand that groups will be used. I have to use this way. I created first query which return the single student all subject within single page. Now second query return only studentId and StudentName, which will be used/combined with first query and than generate report for per page student wise.

Comment: @PetterFriberg: Actually here I used dummy example for Student Table, because actual scenario will be very complex for me to give here with minimal, complex, and verifiable example. I hope you understand my situation.

Comment: without any other information, I could only suggest to use a single query with data properly grouped and (really important) ordered following your group by clause... then you should be able to use N Group bands in order to accomplish what you need... as suggested by Petter, some jrxml or simple input would be really useful

Comment: The answer is yes use grouping (on student) and set isStartNewPage="true" on the group... but without jrxml an good is answer is difficult to give.

Comment: Here its student.Jrxml : https://goo.gl/LROo8L . I am able to create separate page as your instructions. Now I don't know why second page Total includes First page too. How can I separate the Total for every page that data contains.

Comment: Got it. I need to use Group in Variable fields too which will be used for sum for particular subject. Thanks guys for your answer. It helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer and Thanks to Fabio and Petter for help and giving right direction towards my solution.

I used Group Band to bifurcate the new records for another students and which displayed on another page.